# Prolog - Getting Syntax error: Operator expected

Tags: prolog

```
symptom(thermal nociceptors, acrocyanosis).   

symptom(swelling, acrocyanosis).  
symptom(cold temperature, acrocyanosis).  
symptom(discoloration, acrocyanosis).  
symptom(vomit, acrocyanosis).  
symptom(headache, acrocyanosis). 

treatment(acrocyanosis, sympathectomy). 
treatment(acrocyanosis, antibiotics). 
treatment(acrocyanosis, hospitalization). 
treatment(acrocyanosis, shots). 
treatment(acrocyanosis, vasoactive drugs). 

test(acrocyanosis, central cyanosis). 
test(acrocyanosis, laboratory studies). 
test(acrocyanosis, physical examination). 


Illness(Acrocyanosis, Symptom, Treatment,Test) :-
    symptom(Sympt, Acrocyanosis),
    treatment(Acrocyanosis, Treat),
    test(Acrocyanosis, Examin).
```

Need help with

> Syntax error: Operator expected

Comment: I have them all lined up but this website keeps putting them next to each other. when I enter this into prolog I keep getting the syntax error message

Comment: While I understand the down and close votes. A simple formatting of the question makes the problem obvious. The code was pasted in correctly with formatting by the OP, but as many people don't know how to format code with Markdown it only takes a few seconds for use to reformat it for them.

Comment: Up-voting this because it needs some hugs.

Comment: Also, if you take time to actually look at the Prolog facts given, you can see that this might be an actual person in industry vs a new student.

Comment: `symptom(thermal nociceptors, acrocyanosis).` should be `symptom('thermal nociceptors', acrocyanosis).` etc. If you have a space in a single atom, it must be in single quotes. You have this occurring in several places in your facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have facts and predicates.

Facts and predicates need to start with a lower case letter in Prolog because upper case letters are for variables.

In

```
Illness(Acrocyanosis, Symptom, Treatment,Test) :-
    symptom(Sympt, Acrocyanosis),
    treatment(Acrocyanosis, Treat),
    test(Acrocyanosis, Examin).
```

You need to change `Illness` with an upper case `I` to a lower case `i`.

```
illness(Acrocyanosis, Symptom, Treatment,Test) :-
    symptom(Sympt, Acrocyanosis),
    treatment(Acrocyanosis, Treat),
    test(Acrocyanosis, Examin).
```

Comment: @M.S You are welcome. The preferred way to return the kindness is to click on the check mark to the left of this answer to show that you accept it as a correct answer, and to also click on the upward pointing triangle to give it an up-vote. :)